# Infinite loop in a view

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, dapps

How is ethereum network protected against infinite loops in views? In a normal transaction, you have to pay gas fee, so it would be too expensive for you, but calls to views are for free.

For example this:

```
contract Tester {
    
    function loo() public pure returns(string memory){
        uint i = 1;
        uint c = 0;
        while(i == 1){
            c = c + 1;
        }
        return "good";
    }
}
```

I tried to call this in Remix but it crashed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `view` function is executed on-chain, i.e. within mined transaction, it consumes gas, and this protects node from infinite loop.  When executed off-chain via Web3 API, caller is still able to specify gas limit for the execution, see [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

If gas limit is not specified, it is up to particular implementation how to protect from such things, because they affect only the process that executes transaction off-chain, and do not affect other nodes.  Some implementations may be unprotected, and it seems that REMIX is one of such unprotected implementations.

Comment: For example if none is specified geth will use the current block gas limit.